# How yo use Camel as a router between two applications

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb

I am new to fuse esb,I have a requirement where I have two web applications which will be in different servers (applications will be in different Jboss servers and Fuse will be in another physical machine) and they need to communicate using REST protocol via the fuse esb,I know that I have to use camel for routing the incoming request from one application to the another application,can any please share some thoughts or any link where I can get some information.I am frankly clueless at the moment any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: This question/topic has been answered many times in this forum. There are good examples on apache camel site also.

Comment: Hi Tech user,my requirement is that the applications will be in two different servers (physically) where as the fuse esb will be in third server,I am looking at how to configure fuse so that these two applications can communicate.
All the examples I found have the camel router within the application,which I cant do as these are existing applications.I have to use camel to facilitate the communication between the applications.

Comment: Routes connecting web services are usually run outside of the application running the services. Not sure which example you are talking about. If you are looking for running on fuse then check the redhat documentation. I dont think you will get a tutorial here.

Comment: Thank you TechUser,I am kindda understanding camel much better now after going through the documentations once again,and I am much more confident in achieving the solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you have some requirement of exposing the REST API inside FUSE to achieve loose coupling.

You could use [CXFRS](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html) to expose your REST interface if you need to parse the datatypes sent to Java and maybe map them to something else.

Another, somewhat simpler, component is [Restlet](http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html). It allows you to deal with most aspects of REST style interfaces, such as URI parsing.

Since [REST is plain HTTP](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), in some cases you can come a long way using the [servlet](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html)/[http4](http://camel.apache.org/http4.html) components, maybe to simply proxy or route HTTP requests.

In any case, read up on those components and come back with more specific questions, should you have any

Comment: do you know any tutorial or write up which explain in such thing.